# APDU GET DATA not supported command

Tags: android, smartcard, apdu

I'm testing APDU commands transmitting, and I've found a strange issue,
for `GET DATA` command `00:CA:7F:68` I receive an error:

> 6D00: "Instruction code not supported or invalid"

What can be the problem??? I'm able to read `ATR`, send `SELECT` command.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see any connection to android. Want to add something in that respect?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to read the data from the file `7f68`? Can you give more background info? In any case, I think you may be missing the last byte (`LE`) of the apdu, where you specify the maximum amount of bytes expected in your answer.

Comment: Voted up, but the first part of your comments are comments, and not part of the answer. And *normally* you would expect INS handling to be performed before any length parameters are checked. With ISO/IEC 7816-4, where the occurence of status words is never fully specified, it is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

As frequently mentioned, ISO 7816-4 is a weak standard: no card needs to support all commands and can still claim to be standard-compliant. So it may be that your card does

- not at all
- just not in the current state
- just not in the application/DF where you try it (because there no DOs are present)

understand the command, but I don't think it has to do with the 7F68 object number.

Adding an LE byte (as suggested) is definitely worth a try, even if I would expect 67 00 for that cause.